# Need to add range limit of 30 days on 'To date' once user selects 'From date' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Need to add range limit of 30 days on `To date` once user selects `From date` in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

I have tried using it the way its been shown below, but it isn't working.

Tried using `max date` too but it doesn't work dynamically depending on user selection.

Need to use `datepicker` only.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('#csFromdt').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        onSelect : function(selected) {
            $("#csTodt").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
        }
    });

    $("#csFromdt").keyup(function(e) {

        if (e.keyCode != 8) {
            if ($(this).val().length == 2) {
                $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
            } else if ($(this).val().length == 5) {
                $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
            }
        }
    });

    $('#csTodt').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true
        /*maxDays: 10*/
        /*maxDate : '15'*/
    })/*.on('changeDate', function(selected) {
        let csFromdt = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        let csTodt = new Date(csFromdt);
        csTodt = new Date(csTodt.setDate(csTodt.getDate() + 15));
        $('#csTodt').datepicker('setStartDate', csFromdt);
        $('#csTodt').datepicker('setEndDate', csTodt);
      });*/


    $("#csTodt").keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 8) {
            if ($(this).val().length == 2) {
                $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
            } else if ($(this).val().length == 5) {
                $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
            }
        }
    });

    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        maxDate : '0'
    });

});
```

Comment: try this https://makitweb.com/change-date-range-dynamically-jquery-ui-datepicker/

Comment: will you edit it in my code , as solution in the link creates two new variable in which , how many days to be added on our choice is not shown

Answer (score 0):

I tried my best..any query ask me

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      
       // initializing jquery datepicker
       $( "#csFromdt, #csTodt" ).datepicker({
         dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
         changeMonth : true,
         changeYear : true,
       });
     
       $("#csFromdt").change(function(){ 
         var fromdate = $("#csFromdt").val();
     
         // from dd/mm/yy to new date(yyyy, mm, dd) format
         var newdate = fromdate.split("/");
         var nd = new Date(+newdate[2], newdate[1] - 1, +newdate[0]); //newdate[0] = dd; newdate[1] = mm, newdate[2] = yy
         nd.setDate(nd.getDate() + 30); //adding 30 days from  fromdate
         $("#csTodt").removeAttr('disabled'); //disabling the csTodt input box //optional if u disabled todate input box
     
         $('#csTodt').datepicker('option', 'minDate', fromdate); //setting min  date
         $('#csTodt').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', nd); //setting  max date
     
       });
     
     });
  </script>
```